# paypal donate button extra field

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-buttons

I use PayPal API to create a donate button. I want to add extra field "Donation for: " that will be passed on the PayPal website when the user makes the donation.

Here is how I have added the new custom option:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Donation for">
<input type="hidden" name="os0" value="">
```

It works good but on the PayPal website it is passed as simple text. Is there a way to pass this values to the PayPal so on the PayPal website the user will be able to edit this field(input text)?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You probably want to just handle that yourself. Keep in mind, users are finicky. If they have to fill things out on the final payment screen, it gives them extra time to re-think their purchase.

Comment: I want to implement this functionality just in case someone wants to modify the text from the previous step (the website).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `type` attribute on the `os0` field to `text` so it will display to the user and they can edit it before submitting.